# The content type is text/html; charset=utf-8 of the response message does not match the content type of the association (text/xml; charset=utf-8)

Tags: c#, wcf, utf-8

I use in IIS , and visual studio - asp project,
I get this error:

**System.ServiceModel.ProtocolException
HResult=0x80131501
Message=The content type is text/html; charset=utf-8 of the response message does not match the content type of the association (text/xml; charset=utf-8). If you're using a custom encoder, make sure the IsContentTypeSupported service action is properly implemented. The first 1024 bytes of the response were:...**

this is my web.config:

```
<basicHttpBinding>
  <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_ICRMAppsDataProvider"  maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483646" />
      <binding name="DataServiceSoap" />
      <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_IService1" closeTimeout="00:05:00" 
               openTimeout="00:05:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:25:00"
               allowCookies="false" bypassProxyOnLocal="false" maxBufferPoolSize="2147483646"
               maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483646" useDefaultWebProxy="true" textEncoding="utf-8">
          <security mode="TransportCredentialOnly">
            <transport clientCredentialType="Windows" />
          </security>
  </binding>
</basicHttpBinding>
```

and this  server web.config:

```
  <services>
  <service behaviorConfiguration="ManagementServiceBehaviour" name="AService.Service1">
    <endpoint address="" binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="basicHttpBinding" contract="AService.IService1" />
  </service>
  <service behaviorConfiguration="webHttpBehavior" name="AService.RestfulService">
    <endpoint address="" behaviorConfiguration="webHttpBehavior" binding="webHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="webBindingHttp" name="webBinding" bindingName="webBindingHttp" contract="AService.IRestfulService" />
    <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
  </service>
</services>
<bindings>
  <basicHttpBinding>
    <binding name="basicHttpBinding" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" closeTimeout="00:25:00" openTimeout="00:25:00"   receiveTimeout="00:25:00" sendTimeout="00:25:00" textEncoding="utf-8">
      <security mode="TransportCredentialOnly">
        <transport clientCredentialType="Windows" realm="" />
        <message clientCredentialType="UserName" />
      </security>
      <readerQuotas maxDepth="2147483647" maxStringContentLength="2147483647" maxArrayLength="2147483647" maxBytesPerRead="2147483647" maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647" />
    </binding>
  </basicHttpBinding>
  <webHttpBinding>
    <binding name="webBindingHttp" closeTimeout="00:25:00" openTimeout="00:25:00"   receiveTimeout="00:25:00" sendTimeout="00:25:00">
      <security mode="TransportCredentialOnly">
        <transport clientCredentialType="Windows" realm="" />
       
      </security>
      <readerQuotas maxDepth="2147483647" maxStringContentLength="2147483647" maxArrayLength="2147483647" maxBytesPerRead="2147483647" maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647" />

    </binding>
  </webHttpBinding>
</bindings>
```

what is my error???

Answer (score 0):

Generally, this error means that your host has returned an error page.

So you can try using tracking in wcf to find the real problem by following:

1. Right click your web.config and click Edit WCF Configuration.
2. Under Diagnostics section, enable Log Auto Flush, MessageLogging and Tracing and of course specify a path which your host identity has access to write.
3. Check the trace file after you execute that service call and figure out what the real problem is.

Answer (score 0):

I found answer:
The property "Enable 32-Bit Applications" of pool in IIS was TRUE, it is need able FALSE.

[image: setting of pool application:]